# Open PDF from web using custom view

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-reader

I need to open a PDF from web on my custom view. I just need the PDF information and a back button.

I've seen the following library: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

I've implemented like this, but doesn't work.

How Should I do this?

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ReaderActivity">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
class ReaderActivity : BaseAppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader)

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        pdfView.fromUri(Uri.parse("https://si.ua.es/es/documentos/documentacion/pdf-s/mozilla12-pdf.pdf"))
            .pageSnap(true)
            .load()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
val request = Request.Builder().url("URL TO PDF").build()

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback
{
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response)
    {
        if (!response.isSuccessful)
        {
            throw IOException("Failed to download file: $response")
        }

        val stream = ByteArrayInputStream(response.body()?.bytes())
        pdfView.fromStream(stream).load()
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
})
```

Where pdfView is the element importen from that library:  https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Answer (score 1):

`fromUri()` is for a `Uri` that can be used by `ContentResolver`, such as one with a `content` scheme.

If you know that the PDF is very small, you can try `fromStream()` instead of `fromUri()`. Otherwise, you will need to download the PDF first (e.g., to `getCacheDir()`), then use `fromFile()`, as you may run out of memory if you try to use `fromStream()`.

Comment: PDF will be 2-3 pages maximum, so I should go for `fromStream()` I assume.

Comment: @Lechucico: You are welcome to give it a try. You would need to get an `InputStream` on the PDF content from your favorite HTTP client API (e.g., OkHttp).